# Viewing Revit file using ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a Revit file with GPS information in it. Is there any provision to view that Revit model in ArcGIS Web directly without using ArcGIS desktop    by publishing it as a web view and then opening that web view.

Comment: I don't know much about Revit, but if you can export the information, using revit software, to a text format you can load the file and use it. Can you export to `txt`?.

Comment: I was wondering if I could publish a revit file to a WebScene using some API rather than using ArcGIS Pro Desktop